# google analytics counter issues

Tags: google-analytics

Ok first of all, i have the "new" code, the one that is put just before the `</head>` tag

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-#*$!#*$!xx-x']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

</script>
```

The application that uses this code has 5 pages. 
I have put this code in 3 of them (the first 2 and the last one). 
The last page send me an email about what the visitor wants from our site(a form filled by him actually). 
In the last 5 days i received 5 such emails/requests. 
But google analytics only show 1 visit in that page.

Any reason as to why? I dont know how accurate google is for the first two pages, but i know for sure how much trafic/vistis my exit/thank you/email page has. 
So, what's wrong and what should i check? 
Or it's just a google glitch?

**EDIT:**
finally it works. Ignore google's new code. Stick to old code at end of page, before the `</body>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Analytics (GA) can fail to get an accurate count for any number of reasons:

- Javascript is turned off
- User has blocked GA
- A Javascript error in codes before the GA codes prevents it from running
- The GA code is at the bottom of the page and that part is not loaded because

  - The user left the page before it could finish loading
  - A blocking event (e.g., another Javascript) timed out before the GA could run
  - An error on the page prevented the browser from loading GA
- GA itself failed to record the data for whatever reason
- A caching proxy server mangled the page so the GA code was not included or was broken<sup>1</sup>
- Network error
- Browser error

If you want truly accurate visitor information, you need to look at your web server(s) logs, and even then you won't always get it due to caching (local, proxy, etc).

#### Try this

```
<body>
 <div>
  <img src="/images/top.gif" height="1" width="1" alt="" />
 </div>

 ...[page content]...

 <div>
  <img src="/images/bottom.gif" height="1" width="1" alt="" />
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

1. Put web bugs (1x1 transparent images) on your page, one at right after `<body>` and one just before `</body>`.
2. Examine your server logs to determine the percentage of people who successfully load the entire page (each top-bug's entry matches a botom-bug entry in the logs)
3. Calculate the page load time between top and bottom bugs.

This will give you a good idea of what is going on with your pages and whether people are even loading each one in its entirety.

<sup>1</sup> I've actually witnessed this on more than one occasion.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that the analytic code works best in pages that have static elements in them.

If the page:

- Does not render html
- The code is not inside the Html
- There is a redirect

The code will not work correctly.

Check you contact page and make sure the code is in the page where the form resides, or create a static thank you page at the very end of the process, and then put the code in there.

Comment: The code resides just before the </head> tag, as google instructs. No page can be pure "static", even the thank-you page, as content depends on product and membership of customer. Truth be told, user ends up in thank-you page after a couple redirections, all inside the same domain though. I will try to talk to the managers about setting a static thank-you at the end and check then how analytics will behave.

Comment: try putting the code before you close the body tag at the end of the page.

Answer (score 0):

> *The application that uses this code has 5 pages. I have put this code in 3 of them (the first 2 and the last one).*

The tracking code should be on all the pages or the results will be distorted as people *leave* the site and re-enter when they navigate from page to page.

Comment: this is not possible.. 1 page is a redirection page to a bank and the other leads to paypal